# mysql creates a new row instead of updating existing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I'm trying to update a bio column for a specific user, but i get a new row instead. Been through similar questions but cant figure things out for my situation.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['name_of_user'] == $profile_name) {
    $pageOwner = true;
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $bio = $_POST['bio'];

    if (empty($bio)) {
        $error = "Missing Bio";
    } else {
        if ($member_bio->num_rows == 1) {

            if ($query = $db->query("UPDATE user_account SET 'bio'='$bio' WHERE 'id_user'='$id'")) {
                $ok_mesg = "Profile has been updated!!!";

            } else {
                $error = "ERROR on our end";
            }
        } else {
            if ($query = $db->query("INSERT INTO user_account (bio) VALUES('$bio')")) {

                $ok_msg = "Profile has been updated";
            } else {
                $error = "Error on our end";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **warning** your code may be vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Comment: and also add the rest of the if statement

Comment: Your first query is probably failing because no row exists with that user id, so the logic then falls into your else statement. Check your field names. Then validate the $id value prior to running the query.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can directly `UPDATE` if the value is already existing or `INSERT` if it doesn't exist by using `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

But first you need to specify a unique column,

```
ALTER TABLE user_account ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (id_user)
```

if column `ID_USER` is already a primary key then skip the first method. After it has been implemented, you can now use the following syntax

```
INSERT INTO user_account (id_user, bio) 
VALUES($id, '$bio')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bio = '$bio';
```

- [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Works now!!! Thanks for the speedy answers and suggested reading. You guys are great :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the heads up. I'm sure there will be more questions. Will remember next time ;)