# PHP/MySQL PDO/Update Rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm here trying to update my DB rows without deleting/creating new ones all the time. Currently, my DB creates new entries everytime I run this block of code. Instead of spamming my DB, I just want to change some of the values.

```
     <?php
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=dbname", Username, password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 }
catch(PDOException $e){
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

if(isset($_POST['mUsername']))
{
    $mUsername = urldecode($_POST['mUsername']);
    $mEvent = urldecode($_POST['mEvent']);
    $mChat = urldecode($_POST['mChat']);
    $mlongitude = urldecode($_POST['mlongitude']);
    $mlatitude = urldecode($_POST['mlatitude']);

    $sqlUPDATE = "UPDATE users 
                        SET lastEvent=:lastEvent, lastChat=:lastChat,
                            lastLong=:lastLong, lastLatt=:lastLatt 
                      WHERE name=:name";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlUPDATE);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastEvent', $mEvent);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastChat', $mChat);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastLong', $mlongitude);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastLatt', $mlatitude);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $mUsername);
$stmt->execute();
}
echo "successfully updated";
?>
```

My assumption is my final line, the $results area. I believe it's just treating this an a new entry instead of an update. How do I go about just replacing values? some values will not change, like the username, and sometimes longitude/latitude won't need to be changed. Would that have to be a separate query, should I split this in to two scripts? Or could I just enter a blank, null value? Or would that end up overwriting the ACTUAL last coordinates, leaving me with null values? Looking for any help or guides or tutorials. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I am tempted to say RTM! You are preparing a query that has nothing to prepare i.e. No `?` parameters or `names` parameters

Comment: Sorry, I am very beginner in MySQL\pdo and I took my original (insert) code and tried to modify it to update

Comment: You could simply remove `prepare` and `execute` and replace them with `->query` [But again the manual is your friend.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) its in many languages

Comment: Thank you, I am going to favorite the manual from here on out :)

Comment: You may also want to refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754502/mysql-creates-a-new-row-instead-of-updating-existing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lots of syntax error in your code. It is simple to use `bindParam`

```
$sqlUPDATE = "UPDATE users 
                        SET lastEvent=:lastEvent, lastChat=:lastChat,
                            lastLong=:lastLong, lastLatt=:lastLatt 
                      WHERE name=:name";// you forget to close statement in your code

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlUPDATE);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastEvent', $mEvent);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastChat', $mChat);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastLong', $mlongitude);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastLatt', $mlatitude);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $mUsername);
$stmt->execute();
```

read http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score 2):

When using prepared statements, you should also make a habbit of following the set rules. Use named parameters. Try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['mUsername']))
{
    $mUsername = urldecode($_POST['mUsername']);
    $mEvent = urldecode($_POST['mEvent']);
    $mChat = urldecode($_POST['mChat']);
    $mlongitude = urldecode($_POST['mlongitude']);
    $mlatitude = urldecode($_POST['mlatitude']);

    $sqlUPDATE = "UPDATE users SET lastEvent= :lastEvent, lastChat= :lastChat, lastLong= :lastLong, lastLatt= :lastLatt WHERE name= :name";
    $q = $conn->prepare($sqlUPDATE);
    $results = $q->execute(array(':name'=>$mUsername, ':lastEvent'=>$mEvent, ':lastChat'=>$mChat, ':lastLong'=>$mlongitude, ':lastLatt'=>$mlatitude));
}
```

Comment: Hope you dont mind, just remove the unnecessary double quotes around `prepare($sqlUPDATE)`

Comment: @RiggsFolly - i didnt see that, ok, lemme go through that once more

Comment: `lastLatt= :lastLatt WHERE name= :name;"` semicolumn missing

Comment: Also fixed the missing/misplaced semi colon

Comment: @Saty its been noted and fixed by RiggsFolly

Comment: @Saty appreciated, never sifted through the SO's code, just pointed out mistakes. I never realised he was so off...

Comment: I'm still creating new rows in my database :|

Comment: @Saty I may have identified the problem, maybe I should be using my primary key as the reference, instead of the username? and I will edit the original post with my full PHP code.

Comment: Wow! It works! My issue wasn't from the code, it was from my server. For whatever reason the file didn't overwrite itself. Thank you so much for the help guys!